# EFI boot entry variables flicker in and out of existence

Tags: uefi

I have an Asus K55N laptop. It's very finnicky about when it chooses to show, say, an attached USB in the list of available boot entries that I access by pressing `Esc` at boot. That's that. However, if there are boot entries that are saved as `BootXXXX` variables, then I expect to see the same ones always across boots performed with different settings (e.g., secure boot on/off, etc.).

Whst I noticed though is that depending on a combination of factors that I don't understand yet, on one boot I can only see, say, Boot0000, Boot0001, and Boot0003 in efivarfs on one boot. Then, on another, I'll additionally see Boot0005, but Boot0003 will have different entry content than it did before.

Why is happening? I expect that BootXXXX, if it shows up on one boot session, then it will show up in every boot session.